# Generate Different Colors

Tags: swift, return, uicolor

I am making a program in which there are two colors. The first one is random, whilst the second one is a different shade of the first one. The difference between the shades is determined by the variable colorDiff.

```
func generateColors() -> (main: UIColor, diff: UIColor) {
    let colorDiff = findColorDiff()

    let redMain: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255))/255.0
    let greenMain: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255))/255.0
    let blueMain: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255))/255.0
    let main: UIColor = UIColor(red: redMain, green: greenMain, blue: blueMain, alpha: 0.8)

    if (redMain + colorDiff <= 255 && blueMain + colorDiff <= 255 && greenMain + colorDiff <= 255) {
        let redDiff: CGFloat = redMain + colorDiff
        let blueDiff: CGFloat = blueMain + colorDiff
        let greenDiff: CGFloat = greenMain + colorDiff
        let diff: UIColor = UIColor(red: redDiff, green: greenDiff, blue: blueDiff, alpha: 0.8)
        return diff
    } else {
        let redDiff: CGFloat = redMain - colorDiff
        let blueDiff: CGFloat = blueMain - colorDiff
        let greenDiff: CGFloat = greenMain - colorDiff
        let diff: UIColor = UIColor(red: redDiff, green: greenDiff, blue: blueDiff, alpha: 0.8)
        return diff
    }

    return (main, diff)
}
```

The main problem is that I cannot return values from within an "if" loop, so I need a way to be able to return the UIColor "diff" and still be able to do what's within the "if" statement. Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Please, edit your question with some example to understand better what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure that I follow you here, but if you want to be able to return `diff` after having gone through the conditional statements, just declare it before the conditional statement:

```
let main: UIColor = [...]
let diff: UIColor
if [...] {
    [...]
    diff = [...]
} else {
    [...]
    diff = [...]
}
return diff
```

Assuming that you are using Swift >= 1.2 then you can declare an immutable variable and actually set it later, as long as the conditional branches are simple enough for the compiler to be sure that `diff` will always be initialised before it is first used.

Of course, while it is not so good stylistically, you can actually return from either the `if` or `else` since `main` is already initialised and in both cases you are initialising `diff`, so in both you can safely do `return (main, diff)`.